# Modifying Reference to Object to Avoid Protected Setter

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class that is generic like so:

```
class AbstractClass<T>
{
   public T Data {get; protected set;}
}
```

In all cases T is an IEnumerable. In most cases its a List. But in a special case T can be a string, which is a collection of chars. What is the best way to permit Data to be modified when T is a string?

My thought is to simply get the value of Data, then assign it a new value;

```
var data = Obj.Data;
data = "string";
```

Will that do what I expect? Are there any pitfalls? Is there a better way?

Edit:

The underlying reason the setter is protected is because it is most often a collection, and the intent is to new the collection in the constructor. Secondly, and I probably should have added this, the Data object is optionally a INotifyPropertyChanged. There is some boilerplate code in the rest of the class, but the basic premise is that I don't want to worry about tracking the assignment of `Data` in the notifications.

```
class Concrete<T> : AbstractClass<T>
{
    public Concrete(T t)
    {
        Data = t;
    }        
}

string str = "String";
Concrete<string> blah = new Concrete<string>(str);
Console.WriteLine(blah.Data); // "String"
string temp = blah.Data;
temp = "Assign";
Console.WriteLine(blah.Data); // "Assign"
```

I want the last line to print "Assign", but it prints "String". Is there a way to accomplish this without changing the protection? I'm thinking in terms of C++ where the address could just be modified.

Comment: Explain your question some more.

Comment: Why do you need to modify the string? Why do not make setter public or create new instance of object with new `Data` value instead?

Comment: String is an immutable datatype in c#, you can't modify it. I don't know why you want to do this, but maybe using a char array would be easier.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# `string`s are immutable so you can't just edit them like a collection.

However, there are other classes that can be used as mutable strings. I will be using `System.Text.StringBuilder`.

Instead of giving a generic argument of `string`, give it `StringBuilder`:

```
string str = "String";
var blah = new Concrete<StringBuilder>(new StringBuilder(str));
Console.WriteLine(blah.Data); // "String"
// to change the string to "Assign", call Clear() then Append()
blah.Data.Clear();
blah.Data.Append("Assign");
Console.WriteLine(blah.Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, you could use the `ref` keyword. Since c# 7, you can also use `ref` for returning values from a function, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#reference-return-values

However, just because you could, doesn't mean you should. There is probably something wrong with your design if you have to do this.

Comment: It's worth note, that auto-properties cannot return by reference.